# I lost my form W-2. How can I recover it so I can file my claim for an income tax refund?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, income-tax-refund, form-w-2

I received my W-2 form a couple of weeks ago in order to acquire my tax refund for the year 2013. My problem started when notice I could not find my W-2 form anywhere. How can I recover it or ask for a official copy in order to receive my tax refund in a legal way?

Answer (score 4):

Best and fastest (and the one I've used personally): Go to your HR department and if they do payroll in-house, they should be able to produce another one for you.  If they don't, they most likely have an outside company administering (think: ADP) payroll, in which case, they should be able to provide you with either a phone number or website.

Comment: Can you summarize the steps here in your answer in case the link goes dead?

Comment: Sure.  Will you remove the down vote when I do so?